# adding a progress bar

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I have an a windows form application that use one class (its name is `Parser`)
this form has a button and when i click on the windows form application button it call one of the parser class method .

this method simply read text file line after line and write each line to separate file...

i would like to add a progress bar to the form in order to show the progress( it is a very large file )

any idea how to do that? I have in the Parse class 2 property one for the number of line in the file and the second how much lines already checked.

here is my `button2_Click` function

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (this.textBox1 != null & this.textBox2 != null)
      {
           inst.init(this.textBox1.Text, this.textBox2.Text);
           //this.progressBar1.Show();

           inst.ParseTheFile();
           System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Parsing finish successfully"); 
       }
}
```

Comment: You should name your controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((obj) =>
    {
        var lines = File.ReadLines(@"D:\test.txt");
        var count = lines.Count();

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            // some parse work
            Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                progressBar1.Value = (i * 100) / count;
            }));
        }
    });
}
```

In the example above, it simply creates a background thread in order not to block the UI thread, until the `Invoke` method is called.
The `Invoke` method is necessary, in order to manipulate with a `Control` that the current thread isn't the owner of. It takes a delegate, and runs this delegate on the thread that owns the `Control`.

You could even go as far, as making the `foreach` loop parallel, if it's a time consuming task to parse the lines. An example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((obj) =>
    {
        var lines = File.ReadLines(@"D:\test.txt");
        var count = lines.Count();

        Parallel.For(0, count, i =>
        {
            // some parse work
            Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                progressBar1.Value = (i * 100) / count;
            }));
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: @HansPassant, How come? All the code is executing on a background thread. It wont block the UI thread.

Comment: It floods the UI thread with invoke requests, it doesn't get around to doing its regular low priority duties anymore.  Like painting.

Comment: @HansPassant, Touché. It will block the UI thread when it runs the `Invoke` method very, very shortly (0.1ms? maybe even less). However, I would still argue that it's better than the whole UI thread is blocked all the time. Also you dont notice the short freeze (atleast I dont).

Comment: what happened to the Parser class? why do the parsing in the GUI class?

Comment: @StealthRabbi, I assumed that OP knew `// some parse work` should be replaced with the call to the parser method etc. - I'm not sure what you mean by GUI class?

Answer (score 1):

normaly you should go on and write some on what you allready tried.
As I think you are more on the *begining" side I would advise looking into the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and its ProgressChanged event / system (Here is a [intro](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Ashush/BackgroundWorker03082008094954AM/BackgroundWorker.aspx) to it).

Of course you have to move your ParseTheFile-code into this.

For more advanced stuff there are a few options:

- add a parameter to the `ParseTheFile` (for example a [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/018hxwa8.aspx)) that is used to set the progress
- return a [IObservable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx) from your `ParseTheFile` that indicates the progress
- use some static service `ParseTheFile` is using to indicate the progress (not adviced)
- ... (I'm sure other poeple will find a lot more options)

(Please not that most of this options require to use [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get back to your UI-Thread for setting progress-bars value if you use another thread - and I would advise you using another thread if the file is that big)

For starter I would go with the backgroundworker - IMHO it's fine if you don't want to go SOLID (desing patterns/priciples) on your first run ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use Math to Calculate Percentage
Like :

```
//While Reading
NumOfLines++;
int Percentage = (NumOfLines * 100) / TotalLines ;
ProgressBar.Value = Percentage;
```

And probably put int.ParseTheFile(); into a Background Worker and/or within a Thread.