# Visual feedback on long running task

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a long running for-each loop, and was wondering if there was a idiomatic way to add some visual user feedback so the user doesn't think the application crashed.

```
private void btnRunLongRunningTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(string path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"path"), "*.ext", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        var result = LongRunning.Task(path);
        string resultPath = Manipulate(path);
        // write result to resultPath
    }
}
```

This might help: It isn't so much that the task itself takes long, but there will likely be a lot of them.

Any advice on how I can accomplish this? Since I'm given a directory as argument, I was thinking I'd look up how many times the task will be performed, then update a progressbar accordingly, running the task and the update code in a background worker, watching out for crossthread access issues.

Comment: Progress bar? After each iteration you step the progress bar.

Comment: look at using a background worker - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546222/adding-a-progress-bar

Comment: This seems like something that could potentially be done using [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx), specifically [Parallel.Foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) (so long as LongRunning.Task is thread-safe), which may be significantly faster. I've never used it with WinForms before, so I don't know if you could just call it directly or if you'd call Parallel.Foreach in a BackgroundWorker (or [TaskFactory.StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx), which is simpler).

Comment: Just looked into the TPL, and I was wondering if it was still feasible to give visual feedback using a Parallel.ForEach. I understand that this will reduce time required for these tasks, but does that mean I have to drop the ideo of visual feedback? The tasks will still run for a doubt-inducing amount of time.

Comment: For others: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/parallelizing-windows This seems to describe what I'm asking in the comments.

Comment: @lowerkey You have several entirely seperate tasks here, first you need to ensure that you're not blocking the UI thread so that the application isn't frozen.  Next you need to update the UI based on the progress of a background task.  Finally, you may want to actually execute the code in parallel using multiple threads, and not just a single background thread.  You can do the first two, the last one, or all of them; they're independent.  As for the link, the progress isn't quite right in that case, but it's an okay solution for very little effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could move the work to a BackgroundWorker and use the ReportProgress method.

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    // do work
    worker.ReportProgress((100 * i) / count);
}

private void MyWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender,
    ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    taskProgressBar.Value = Math.Min(e.ProgressPercentage, 100);
}
```

Comment: +1 `BackgroundWorker` may be easier to implement for someone who is new to threading.